# Database of built-in data linked with application

Tags: c#

I'm coding an application in C#, and I need like, a database of built in data that's linked with the application. I wont ever need to edit the data, I just need easy access to it.

Basically I want it so I have data built into the application that's represented like this:

```
Book Title            Book Author
SomeBookTitle         SomeBookAuthor
SomeOtherBookTitle    SomeOtherBookAuthor
```

Kinda like that? Easy accessible, and preferably linked with the application somehow, so I only have 1 executable file. Oh and there might be a lot of data...

Comment: You realize that "I wont ever need to edit the data" are famous last words, right? ;)

Comment: @Daniel Earwicker Probably alot.
@The Evil Greebo Well if i ever want to edit the data, I could like rebuild the application with the updated data.
The book example was just an example, im not necessarily using books lol

Comment: Look into NHibernate. It maps your code to the database

Comment: How often are you going to be using/reading this data?  Are you pulling it into memory?  Or are you going to be accessing it like a db (on demand)

Comment: Id like to pull the data into memory, so i could have book titles in a combobox, and then a readonly textbox under, and when i select the title it displays the author in the textbox.

Comment: If you just say "alot", then this isn't a real question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest a different approach than the others so far.

I wouldn't use a resource file because presumably you don't want to hard code every reference to every line in the resource file.  100 "books" would mean 100 distinct resources to code against.

And if you want self contained deployment, 3rd party components are problematic.

My suggestion:  Put all your data in an XML structure and put that XML in a resource file as one single resource.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<books>
    <book Author="Joe" Title="Joe's Awesome"/>
    <book Author="Fred" Title="Joe's Stupid"/>
    <book Author="Tim" Title="Who's Joe"/>
</books>
```

Put that in your resource file as MyData

Then you can iterate it with:

```
XDocument xd = new XDocument(XDocument.Parse(myResources.MyData));
foreach(XElement xe in xd.Elements) { // blah blah blah }
```

Or you can use LinqToXml or any number of alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have two fields you could use a Resource File and use the key as your bookname and the value as the author.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.80).aspx

You could also add a Sql Server compact database
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg606540.aspx

Comment: +1 If you only have a few values that don't change (and it sounds like the OP does) it's a lot easier and requires less overhead to just embed the values in a resource file.

Comment: IF you only have a few values, sure.  If you have 100 "books" then now you've got MyResources.Book1, MyResources.Book2, MyResources.Book3, etc.  It's about like using columns to represent months in a year - each year you need to add 12 more columns.  And he DOES say there might be a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

As far as your database needs are concerned, an embedded database like SQLite or SQL Server CE should do the trick. Kinda like maybe... ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can write your code something like this:

```
SqlDataReader rdr = null;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection( /*Connection string*/ );

SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("select * from  Books", conn);
conn.Open();
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read())
{
   string bookTitle= (string)rdr["Book Title"];
   string bookAuthor = (string)rdr["Book Author"];

   Console.Write("{0,-25}", bookTitle);
   Console.Write("{0,-20}", bookAuthor );

   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: He never mentioned that he didn't wanted to use database, though using xml file to store data is good idea but my answer isn't wrong either.

Comment: He states that he wants to know where/how to store this data.  You have answered neither of those questions.

Comment: he didnt asked "where/how to store this data" in entire page, he need some mechanism for "easy access to hid data" and i provided one mechanism to access data stored in database. I Think you need to read question carefully...

Comment: "Basically I want it so i have data built into the application..."  How does your answer provide a solution to this problem?  Besides that, you aren't closing your connection, so your example isn't even correct.